# SQL help, not sure of what function to use

Tags: sql, distinct, duration

So here I have an SQL query I'm trying to use to find a worker who has worked the most days on a project

```
SELECT pw.project_id, pw.worker_id, w.worker_name, DATEDIFF(leavedate, joindate) 'Time Worked in Days' 
FROM projectworker pw 
INNER JOIN worker w ON pw.worker_id=w.worker_id
```

When I run the query I get this:

```
project_id  worker_id  workername  Time Worked in Days
1                  1        mx      9
1                  1        mx      1087
1                  2        red     740
1                  3        fed     1522
2                  5        meo     1847
2                 12        bull    1462
4                  3        fed     1126
4                  6        mao     4018
4                  7        polly   1858
4                  3        fed     3318
5                  8        max     365
5                  9        drudge  731
5                  10       max     33
5                  12       bull    428
5                  1        mx      793
```

So as you can see in project 1, worker 1 (mx) worked twice, once for 9 days once for 1087 days. I was wondering how I can set up my query so that his name only shows up one time, and it combines his time worked (so that it shows 1096). I tried using SELECT DISTINCT but that gave me an error. Any suggestions? Sorry if this is a trivial question I'm new to SQL! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Basic SQL aggregation query. Look into `SUM` with `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to sum worked time. Result will be sorted with greatest worked time first.

```
SELECT pw.project_id, pw.worker_id, w.worker_name, 
       SUM(DATEDIFF(leavedate, joindate)) 'Time Worked in Days' 
FROM projectworker pw 
INNER JOIN worker w ON pw.worker_id=w.worker_id
group by pw.project_id, pw.worker_id, w.worker_name
order by SUM(DATEDIFF(leavedate, joindate)) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY`. Fields to group are `projectId`, `workerId` and then select sum of the time

```
SELECT pw.project_id, pw.worker_id, w.worker_name, SUM(DATEDIFF(leavedate, joindate)) 'Time Worked in Days' 
FROM projectworker pw 
INNER JOIN worker w ON pw.worker_id=w.worker_id
GROUP BY pw.project_id, pw.worker_id, w.worker_name
```